# Bootstrap UI Collapse directive behaving weird

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm a bit stumped with a problem with the bootstrap.ui module for AngularJS.

This is my HTML:

```
<nav id="sidebar">      

    <ul id="main-nav" class="open-active">

        <li ng-controller="CollapseCtrl" class="dropdown">              
            <a ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed" href="javascript:;">
                <i class="fa fa-wrench"></i>
                Verktøy
                <span class="caret"></span>
            </a>                

            <ul ng-show="isCollapsed" class="sub-nav">
                <li>
                    <a href="#/vernerunde">
                        <i class="fa fa-th-list"></i> 
                        Ny Vernerunde
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#/interaksjon">
                        <i class="fa fa-gears"></i> 
                        Ny Interaksjon
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#/brukerstyring">
                        <i class="fa fa-user"></i> 
                        Brukerstyring
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li ng-controller="CollapseCtrl" class="dropdown">
            <a ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed" href="javascript:;">
                <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                Lister
                <span class="caret"></span>
            </a>                

            <ul ng-show="isCollapsed" class="sub-nav">
                <li>
                    <a href="#/list">
                        <i class="fa fa-desktop"></i> 
                        Alle
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>                   
    </ul>

</nav>
```

And this is the controller responsible for the `isCollapsed` model:

```
controllers.controller('CollapseCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.isCollapsed = false;
});
```

I've also made a small gif which I'm going to throw in that shows my actual problem. Now, I'm not too sure whether or not it's present in the gif, but it seems if I click the first element in the list, it works. Then when that first element has been toggled, and I click the element underneath, it totally breaks apart.

[image: gif showing my problem]

EDIT1:

Okay, I changed the directive from `ng-show=""` to `collapse=""`, still using "`isCollapsed`". Now it's working, but the height of the box that's collapsed is too small.

[image]

Comment: Did you try making collapse height auto?

Comment: Yes, but the problem is a css scope higher, there's inline styling being generated by the directive, so it's unchangable.

Maybe what I could do is set the height of a higher element to auto?

Answer (score 1):

Though I don't have much insight into the problem I strongly suspect that the issue is in here:

```
<a ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed" href="javascript:;">
    <i class="fa fa-wrench"></i>
    Verktøy
    <span class="caret"></span>
</a>
```

Mind that the `ng-click` is executed once , but once a variable changes, the scope lifecycle will recalculate the scope several times. And once a variable which depends on isCollapsed will change, the scope is re-calculated again, and so forth.  This might explain the unusual openings and closings of the title panes. Although I don't see exactly why `isCollapse` is recalculated.

Solution: Move it as a method inside the controller.

Comment: Got it, will try and report!

Comment: Hi, again. This didn't resolve the issue, but atleast got it to work a bit smoother.

Comment: Yeah, I made this fiddle -- http://fiddle.jshell.net/6Se8K/1/. Normally it should work fine as you created it. Perhaps you can enhance this fiddle with the rest of your code, because there clearly is something outside the code above which is triggering this behavior.